# postgresql: converting CTE column to array

Tags: postgresql, function, common-table-expression

I am trying to convert one of the columns of CTE to array. I keep on getting "syntax error at or near" followed by "ret := array(".

My objective is that the table I am returning from `a_function()` in example below is **stored** as a variable to be referred later in function. But I could not find a syntax to do so. So, instead of using CTE, if I can use something else, that would work just as nicely.

Note: I am trying this in pgAdmin III.

```
create or replace function a_function()
--returns int[][] as
returns table(column1 int, column2 int) as
$body$
begin
   return query
      select 1,2;


end;
$body$
language 'plpgsql'
;



--select * from a_function();

create or replace function test_a_function()
returns void as
$body$
declare ret int[];
begin
   with ret_cte(column1, column2) as (
      select * from a_function()
   )

   ret := array(
      select column1 from ret_cte
   )
   ;
   --raise notice '%', array_to_string(ret, ',');
end;
$body$
language 'plpgsql'
;

--select test_a_function();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to convert one of the columns of CTE to array. I keep on getting **"syntax error at or near" followed by "ret := array("**

You could use:

```
ret :=array(with ret_cte(column1, column2) as (
               select * from a_function()
            )
            select column1 from ret_cte
       );
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/MLXB1838)**

Comment: Correct, the problem is that you can't use variable assignation as a part of `WITH`. That's why there's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can be built and returned using the [array_agg()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html) function.  For example, your second function could be written using a SQL language function that returns the array as follows:

```
create or replace function test_a_function()
returns int[] as
$body$
   select array_agg(column1) from a_function();
$body$
language 'sql';
```

Alternatively, you can assign the array to a variable like this:

```
create or replace function test_a_function()
returns void as
$body$
declare
    ret int[];
begin
   select array_agg(column1) 
   into ret
   from a_function();

   raise info '%', ret;
end;
$body$
language 'plpgsql';
```